# How to use Microsoft.Workflow.Compiler.exe (wfc.exe) from command line?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, xaml

I think it's intended for obsolete now XOML files and I know it's better to use msbuild.[I've found this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms734733(v=vs.90).aspx) - the **Microsoft.Workflow.Compiler.exe** seems buggy and not capable to print a help message. I just get :

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: The compiler process was not given arguments or was given an invalid set of arguments. When invoking the process the expected arguments are the path to the compiler input and the path to where the output should be placed.
Parameter name: args
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Compiler.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

With passed XAML file and /output parameter it prints messages like :

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 2. Expecting element 'CompilerInput' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Workflow.Compiler'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'Window', namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlReader reader)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Compiler.Program.ReadCompilerInput(String path)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Compiler.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

The executable is located in **%WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319**

*The reason why I'm experimenting with this is because it looks is capable to compile single XML file with embedded C#/Visual basic code and is not sensitive  to the file extensions - and eventually I'll be able able to create selfcompiled  cmd scripts with [similar technique](https://gist.github.com/npocmaka/7256cf3654a83b4335c9).*

Comment: Have you tried a decompiler? It looks as if the command line would by `<exe> INFILE OUTFILE`, where `INFILE` is a data contract serialized version of an internal class that defines the files to compile/include and `OUTFILE` is a serialized version of the results. Hmm.

Comment: @Christian.K so I can used directly from command line? And eventually I'll need additional tool for serialization ?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you need an extra tool to serialize the compiler (tool) input. Whether that all is feasible, especially since it doesn't seem to be document / supported (?), you have to decide.